# Add Animation to views using Class in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm using a lot of animation in my app. I create all these animation in `xml` files. Everything is working fine but I want to write code in useful manner.

Here is dummy code Example:

**Res/anim (Directory)**

```
   type1_anim1.xml
   type1_anim2.xml
   type1_anim3.xml
   type1_anim4.xml

   type2_anim1.xml
   type2_anim2.xml
   type2_anim3.xml
   type2_anim4.xml
```

**MainAvtivity.java**

```
   // Reset of the code
   public void button1(View view){
            Animation anim1= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.type1_anim1);
            Animation anim2= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.type1_anim2);
            Animation anim3= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.type1_anim3);
            Animation anim4= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.type1_anim4);

       view1.startAnimation(anim1);
       view2.startAnimation(anim2);
       view3.startAnimation(anim3);
       view4.startAnimation(anim4);

   }
   public void button2(View view){
            Animation anim1= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.type2_anim1);
            Animation anim2= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.type2_anim2);
            Animation anim3= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.type2_anim3);
            Animation anim4= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.type2_anim4);

       view1.startAnimation(anim1);
       view2.startAnimation(anim2);
       view3.startAnimation(anim3);
       view4.startAnimation(anim4);

   }
```

Right now I'm doing something like above one I want something like this one.

**CustomAnimation.java**

```
public class CustomAnimation{
    public anim1(){
          // here goes all animations of type1 e.g type1_anim1.xml etc
    }
    public anim2(){
          // here goes all animations of type2 e.g type2_anim1.xml etc
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
  public void button1(View view){
      anim1();
  }
  public void button2(View view){
      anim2();
  }
```

How it is possible.

Comment: what type of animation you need to done in code ?  (i.e Fade, Zoom )

Comment: create util class and pass the view and context as to animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i write simple custom animation class using xml Animation,

CustomAnimation.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

/**
 * Created by Magesh on 4/10/2017.
 */

public class CustomAnimation
{
    private static CustomAnimation mThis = new CustomAnimation();
    public enum AnimationType {
        FadeIn, ZoomIn, Blink
    }
    private CustomAnimation()
    {

    }

    public void startAnimation(Context context, AnimationType animationType, View view)
    {
        Animation animation = null;
        switch (animationType)
        {
            case FadeIn:
            {
                animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);
            }
            break;
            case ZoomIn:
            {
                animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.zoom_in);
            }
            break;
            case Blink:
            {
                animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.blink);
            }
            break;
        }

        view.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    public static CustomAnimation getThis()
    {
        return mThis;
    }

}
```

You can simply call this method from Activity like below ,

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private Button mBtnClick;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mBtnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mBtnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CustomAnimation customAnimation = CustomAnimation.getThis();
                customAnimation.startAnimation(getApplicationContext(), CustomAnimation.AnimationType.Blink, mTextView);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Output Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: I want animation in xml not in java I just want to implement it using java class

Comment: @FiverrProjects now i updated my answer, you can use above code

Comment: Passing view is a good way ? Because you are passing view to customAnimation. is there any heap memory problem ?

Comment: @FiverrProjects you can pass view to any class no issue. if you feel bad you can change startAnimation() as return method and return Animation Object. Passing Context may be raise heap issue. use getApplicationContext() not this or MainActivity.this